# Binary Tree AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insertRight'

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, tree, binary-tree

I have been reading the book [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/NodesandReferences.html#fig-treerec) and I am trying to complete the last exercise that asks you to build a binary tree. Yet I am having a hard time understanding how the tree items get added.

**Here is the BinaryTree Class:**

```
  class BinaryTree(object):
        def __init__(self, rootObj):
            self.key = rootObj
            self.leftChild = None
            self.rightChild = None

        def insertLeft(self, newNode):
            if self.leftChild == None:
                self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
            else:
                t = BinaryTree(newNode)
                t.leftChild = self.leftChild
                self.leftChild = t

        def insertRight(self, newNode):
            if self.rightChild == None:
                self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
            else:
                t = BinaryTree(newNode) # make a new BinaryTree first
                t.rightChild = self.rightChild
                self.rightChild = t 

        def getRightChild(self):
            return self.rightChild

        def getLeftChild(self):
            return self.leftChild

        def setRootVal(self, obj):
            self.key = obj 

        def getRootVal(self):
            return self.key
```

And when I try to add items to the tree, they don't really do what I expect.

For example if I executed the following code:

```
a = BinaryTree('a')
a.insertLeft('b')
a.getLeftChild().insertRight('c')
a.insertRight('w')
a.getRightChild().insertRight('x')   #this one raises an error
```

The last line causes an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insertRight'`
Why is this line causing this error? Why doesn't the 3rd line raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insertRight` method inserts on the **left**:

```
def insertRight(self, newNode):
    if self.rightChild == None:
        self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        #    ^^^^
```

As such, all your `rightChild` attributes will forever remain `None`.

You should use `is` to test for `None`:

```
def insertRight(self, newNode):
    if self.rightChild is None:
        self.rightChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
    else:
        t = BinaryTree(newNode) # make a new BinaryTree first
        t.rightChild = self.rightChild
        self.rightChild = t
```